# What semantic field underlies 涵 for it to mean 'soak, immerse' and 'tolerate, be lenient'?

Tags: etymology

Fortunately I can guess a possible ratiocination of this etymology: [5 Houseplants You Can’t Kill by Overwatering](https://www.apartmenttherapy.com/water-tolerant-plants-262128). Because these plants won't die even if soaked, immersed, or wet, they can tolerate, forigve your over-watering. They are lenient to the wrongdoing of over-watering. Am I correct? I screenshot [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E6%B6%B5).

[image]
[涵 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B6%B5#Chinese)

> **涵**
>
> 1. to [soak](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soak); to [wet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wet)
> 2. to [tolerate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tolerate); to [forgive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forgive); to be [lenient](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lenient)
> 3. to [immerse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/immerse)
> 4. a [culvert](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/culvert)
> 5. *Alternative form of* [含](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%90%AB#Chinese) (“to [contain](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contain), to [bear](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bear)”).

Answer (score 1):

The semantic extension is as follows:

- *To be soaked in water*
- *To have a large capacity to hold water*
- *To have a large capacity to tolerate <sub><s>bullshit</s></sub>*
- *To be lenient* (e.g. lenient on someone for their wrongdoings)

---

**References:**

- 《漢語大詞典》

Answer (score 1):

> 涵，水泽多也。
>
> "涵" means much water.
>
> ——《说文(Shuowen)》，an ancient Chinese dictionary

I think, the original meaning of "涵" is many rivers or lakes. Then, "涵" has a new meaning: Infiltrate; moisturize(浸润;滋润). After that, "涵" also means "contain(包含，包容)". The last meaning of "涵" is "forgiveness and tolerance(包涵，宽容)"

How does "涵" mean from "contain" to "tolerance"?

> 宰相肚里能撑船。
>
> You can even row a boat in the belly of the Prime Minister Wang Anshi.
>
> ——中国俗语/Chinese saying, it means a tolerant person like Wang Anshi.

(There is also a Chinese idiom involved: a big belly can contain more things, including others' mistakes(大肚能容). It's about a big belly monk Budai, also known as Mile Buddha(布袋和尚，大肚弥勒佛).)

A lake(涵) can hold a lot of water, so the ancient Chinese compared water to people's mistakes and tolerant people to lakes.